# Did V escape before or after the St. Mary's virus event?

Tags: plot-explanation, v-for-vendetta

In the movie ***V for Vendetta***, did V blow up the Larkhill camp and escape before or after the St. Mary's virus event? I'm trying to figure if the Norsefire perfected the virus and the cure during the trials on V or post his escaping? Is there anything that points to this timeline?

Answer (score 2):

In the source material, V escaped from Larkhill five years prior to the events in the book. This happened about a decade or two after the Nuclear War that devastated the rest of the world, and caused panic/riots in England (England was not part of the war, but food and other supplies are limited). In the Film, the St. Mary's Virus at Three Waters takes place of the Nuclear War. This was a false flag event used by the Fascist party, inconsistently called Norsefire, to gain power. They used the "terrorist biological attack" in order to rally support for their fascist political ideas.

The concentration camps in both versions are supposed to have come after these events. Without the nuclear war or St. Mary's virus, there would have been no way the concentration camps would exist, and neither V or lesbian actress Valerie Page would have been imprisoned.

Comment: That's the part that wouldn't make sense then @cde, the virus attack of St.Mary’s is developed in Larkhill. Those are the tests on V.

Comment: In the film, there is a war and then there is the virus attack. I think there are two events.

Comment: @Tivep no, there is no war in the film. Specifically, the virus was used because `In place of the nuclear war of the novel version, biological weapons are used instead. Alan Moore later states in the foreword to the trade paperback edition of V for Vendetta that scientists now felt that even a "limited" nuclear war was not survivable. Thus biological weapons would today be considered more plausible.`

Comment: @Tivep and that would mean that there were concentration camps BEFORE Norsefire/the fascist were in control of England, AND that the control happened within 5 years, as V has only been around for 5 years as V.

Comment: the Larkhill human subjects are for what then? If not finding the strand of virus? There is a mention of the war in America extending to England in the movie as well. It's not nuclear in the movie.

Comment: @Tivep that mention, if it was real news and not just false propaganda used to control the english public, would be current day, not in the past. As for the Larkhill subjects, they were human subjects in the comic as well, which had no virus. Just like real life, humans have been used as lab rats for *any number of reasons* not limited to bio-weapons. The comic experiment http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batch_5 was a hormone treatment, and caused the subjects to grow extra organs.

Comment: this is what V says "The project, however, ends violently, but the efforts of those involved are not in vain, for a new ability to wage war is born from the blood of one of the victims. Imagine a virus the most terrifying virus you can, and then imagine that you and you alone have the cure, how best to use such a weapon? It's at this point in our story that along comes a spider. He's a man seemingly without a conscience, and it is he who suggests that their target should not be an enemy of the country but rather the country itself" The virus is clearly from larkhill based on trials on V

Comment: @Tivep that also clearly says it happens after V escapes. But then consider Evey. Her brother died from the St. Mary's Virus, and her parents became political dissidents because of it, and that caused them to be arrested in front of Evey when she was a child. That's nearly 20 years give or take. Assuming V was 25~30 when he was locked up, that mean it took him 20 years to do what he's doing, instead of 5 like in the comics. 20 years and none of the villains have aged? The movie timeline is ambiguous at best, and V and Norsefire are both unreliable narrators.

Comment: good point. Looks like there is some timeline error then. However if we assume Evey to be around 20 years of age, even 8 years before the events of the movie would make her 12 years. This would make her the child that witnesses her parents being black-bagged. 1 year prior to that would be the virus attack. 10-12 years of aging of the villains is still believable. Lilliman and Prothero are shown during the time of Larkhill. They've tried to make them look much younger too.

Comment: @cde in the film V indeed says that he's been waiting 20 years for this moment.